# How to get a shape's X and Y coordinates from Visio?

Tags: vba, visio

I have a shape on a sheet and I have its "ID".

I want X-Y coordinates from the shape.

I tried the following code:

```vb
Set shpObj = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(blockID)
Set celObj = shpObj.Cells("pinX")
localCent = celObj.Result("inches")
LocationX = Format(localCent, "000.0000")

Set shpObj = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(blockID)
Set celObj = shpObj.Cells("pinY")
localCent = celObj.Result("inches")
LocationY = Format(localCent, "000.0000")
```

I am getting numbers, but they never change. I think I am getting a local shape coordinate not the sheet coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Please try use [XYtoPage method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.xytopage).

[image]
Hope my article can helps, please [read via Google translate](https://gist-github-com.translate.goog/Surrogate-TM/caa23fb3d3816b19c5d0aecfbc209c71?_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp).